# How to unwrap an [NSPasteboardItem] in swift?

Tags: swift

I am trying to read string from clipboard in swift:

```
let pasteBoard = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
let o = pasteBoard.pasteboardItems[0].stringForType("public.utf8-plain-text")
```

Got this error:

Error: value of optional type '[NSPasteboardItem]?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pasteboardItems` is an Optional. You have to unwrap it *before* you can take its index:

```
let o = pasteBoard.pasteboardItems?[0] // ...
```

Or, if you are absolutely certain that there are items:

```
let o = pasteBoard.pasteboardItems![0] // ...
```

It would be better, however, to unwrap it in an `if` clause and proceed only if it is not `nil`:

```
if let items = pasteBoard.pasteboardItems? {
    let o = items[0] // ...
}
```

Comment: Learning by doing and from mistakes is also a way of learning. People are different.